# Switching a Database Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with URL's based on scientific names. For example, if the value 'Canidae' is in my database, then my site will display a page at MySite/canidae.

There are a few scientific names that are duplicates. For example, there are two fish general named Leptocephalus, while Phyllanthus is the name of both a plant genus and a bird genus.

If I navigate to MySite/bison - then it recognizes its status as a mammal page through its parent-child relationships. Genus Bison's parent is Bovidae, and its parent is Artiodactyla, and so on until we get to mammals (Mammalia).

So imagine we have a duplicate scientific name - Myname. Let's say one is a mammal with a parent named Mammus and the other is a fish with a parent named Fishus.

If we navigate to MySite/myname, the page recognizes itself as a mammal by default. I'd like to know if there's a way to enable visitors to change the page to a "fish" page by clicking a button or link that changes the parent from Mammus to Fishus. In other words, the URL will still be the same - MySite/myname. But if a visitor clicks a button or link, the content will change from the mammal content to the fish content.

Comment: Seems to me you could write your query in a way that checks for multiples (duplicates) of "myname". Then each of those will find their ultimate parent. Finally echo "parent" buttons on the page `for each` duplicate, filtering out the current parent.

Comment: I kind of get it, but how does each multiple "find its ultimate parent"?

Comment: By not relying on the name (or not soly on the name) but on an (additional) id.

Comment: You tagged PHP and MySQL yet have provided no context of how you currently use these for the mentioned behaviour. How are people meant to suggest something better when it's not clear how you've currently programmed it? Also, emphasis on what Michael has said: caching a hidden value that changes the action of a (seemingly) human-readable and bookmark-prone URL seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Michael - sqlbot to the extent that you should have more descriptive URLs for two reasons

1. It's more user friendly
2. It's more search engine friendly

So let's start by saying we are at this page [www.examplesite.com/fish/myname](http://www.examplesite.com/fish/myname) which is showing us content about "MyName" the "Fish"

Interestingly there is also a "Mammal" as well. So we provide buttons to allow the visitor to view that content as well.

This is how we do it...

Suppose you have three tables, like this...

[image]

As you can see we have two "Animals" called "MyName"... but if you trace them back you will see that ID #2 is a Mammal and ID #5 is a Fish
So... "MyName" has two parent IDs

We query the database to get all the information we need using `JOIN`

```
$name = 'MyName';
$sql = "SELECT Animals.*, Species.*, ParentTable.* FROM Animals JOIN Species ON Animals.subcatid = Species.id JOIN ParentTable ON Species.parentid = ParentTable.id WHERE Animals.name=:name";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll();
```

We then echo the buttons to the page linking them to their own unique URL

```
<?php foreach($row as $id) { ?>
<input name="switch" type="button" value="<?php echo $id['name'] ?>" onclick="goToURL('self','/<?php echo $id['name'] ?>/MyName');return document.MM_returnValue">
<?php } ?>
```

And here is the js for the button action

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function goToURL() { //v3.0
var i, args=goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like posting answers that say "don't do what you are trying, do something different," but it seems appropriate here, for one reason in particular:

If the content is different, there's a fairly strong case to be made that the URL should also be different.

The URL should be the determinant of what is displayed.  Otherwise, best case, your content isn't search-engine-friendly.

If I share a link to your site, it doesn't make sense for me to have tell someone "go to example.com/myname, which will show a mammal with a coincidentally-similar name, so then you have to click 'fish.'"  Fishy, indeed.

Consider this, too: even if /bison is unambiguous, a better design might be to "301" redirect the browser to the "page" at /animalia/chordata/mammalia/eutheria/artiodactyla/bovidae/bovinae/bison.

If an ambiguity exists, present a "disambiguation" page (as done by Wikipedia, though yours would be automatically generated) offering the canonical links to the possible matches, instead of redirecting directly to the single matching page as you would do in the majority of cases.

The bison example assumes you don't go down to species level, otherwise it's also ambiguous, with bison as genus and species in *Bison bison*, genus only in *Bison bonasus*, etc.

Further reading: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en